# How to store Model methods separately?

Tags: django, django-models

I have an `AbstractUser` model which adds about 20 custom model methods. I want to store these methods properly and idea is to sort it by logic, for example `AdminMethods`, `PaidUserMethods` etc.
I tried to use `models.Manager` but it dont let me get user instance via `self`. How can I store that methods properly? Thanks!

Comment: `models.Manager` is the class used to create QuerySets on your model (`objects = default_manager()`). You could define new python classes to manage various parts of your models, assigning them to a property in the model's initialiser (passing the model itself to the initialiser where you assign them in turn to some instance property). But that would add a layer to calling the methods, e.g. `self.admin = AdminMethods(self)` which would lead to  `myObject.admin.publish()`. Or you can just namespace your methods by convention e.g. `myObject.admin_publish()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, couldn't you create children classes (possibly abstract) that inherit from `AbstractUser` and implement the methods they need?

Like for example:

```
    AdminUser(AbstractUser, ABC):
        #implement all admin methods

    PaidUser(AbstractUser, ABC):
        #implement all paid user methods
```

Comment: Good idea, but I think he wants the methods to apply to all users, while in your answer, this leads to different tables in the db for different types of user. One way to avoid this would be to make the subclasses be proxy models: `class AdminUser(myUser): class Meta: proxy = True`. The only thing is, you can only call the methods of the proxy model on instances initialised as the proxy and not on the instances initialised as the parent model. But that might be a good solution.

Comment: Here's the [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) to proxy models documentation.